# Rails DateTime helper logic

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, view-helpers

Quick question. I am using the distance_of_time_in_words helper to check how many days an object was created. This works fine but I dont want it to have to go 24 hrs before it counts a day but want it to count "1" day once it is "00:00"

eg distance_of_time_in_words("2016-08-11 11:00", "2016-08-12 00:00") should be 1 day but it is 13 hrs

I want that once it passes "00:00" it should count as a 1 day?

Comment: Keep in mind that the logic you propose strongly depends on what time zone the observer is in. If you're serving this value from your server, there's a good chance your visitors won't be in the same time zone. (Considering that... is the custom logic and effort required to meet this arbitrary requirement really worth it?)

Comment: very true will keep that in mind... but will be working with only my time zone for now. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use

```
time_ago_in_words(date_item_was_created.at_midnight)
```

time_ago_in_words allows you to forgo adding the 'now' time* and by moving the created-at date back to midnight, you'll cross the one-day mark
at the next midnight. According to the [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words), it should give you 'round' days for anything over a day, which sounds like what you're after.

*You can continue to use distance_of_time_in_words if you're not comparing to the current time.

Comment: oh smart smart all I really need is the at_midnight

Answer (score 0):

This is what you meant I guess.

```
def distance_of_time_in_words(time1,time2)

  d1 = Time.parse(time1.to_s).to_date.strftime("%d").to_i
  d2 = Time.parse(time2.to_s).to_date.strftime("%d").to_i
  seconds = Time.parse(time2.to_s)- Time.parse(time1.to_s)
  hours = seconds/3600

  if d2-d1 >= 1
    return "#{(d2-d1).to_s} days"
  else
    return "#{hours.to_s} hours"
  end

end
```